# Предотвращение утечки данных SQL C#

Tags: c#, sql, access

Проблема с утечкой информации.Пропадает информация из полей access. То ли при запуске программы не получается подключится к бд access,то ли какой то баг моей проги.
У меня 2 textbox,1 image (загружается пользователем),1 Listbox.

Как мне оптимизировать мой код чтобы внесенная информация не пропадала?
UPD 2

**ВСЕ teb.. это комбобоксы**

```
private void vnecti(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {


        if (nametext.Text.Equals("") && text.Text.Equals(""))
        {
            MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show("Нужно ввести название рецепта и текст рецепта");

        }
        else
        {

            string klantId = nametext.Text; //textbox
            string klantNaam = text.Text; //textbox



            System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection conn = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection();
            conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=Database777.mdb;";



            String ticketno = klantId;
            String Purchaseprice = klantNaam;



            if (desert.IsSelected)
            {

                conn.Open();

                String my_querry = "INSERT INTO Десерт([Название рецепта], [Текст рецепта]) VALUES('" + ticketno + "','" + Purchaseprice + "')";



                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(my_querry, conn);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();

            }



        if (ocnov.IsSelected)
        {

            conn.Open();

            String my_querry = "INSERT INTO Основное([Название рецепта], [Текст рецепта]) VALUES('" + ticketno + "','" + Purchaseprice + "')";



            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(my_querry, conn);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();

        }

        if (salat.IsSelected)
        {
            conn.Open();


            String my_querry = "INSERT INTO Салат([Название рецепта], [Текст рецепта]) VALUES('" + ticketno + "','" + Purchaseprice + "')";



            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(my_querry, conn);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();

        }

        if (vipech.IsSelected)
        {

            conn.Open();

            String my_querry = "INSERT INTO Выпечка([Название рецепта], [Текст рецепта]) VALUES('" + ticketno + "','" + Purchaseprice + "')";



            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(my_querry, conn);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();

        }


        if (sup.IsSelected)
        {
            conn.Open();


            String my_querry = "INSERT INTO Суп([Название рецепта], [Текст рецепта]) VALUES('" + ticketno + "','" + Purchaseprice + "')";



            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(my_querry, conn);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();

        }


            var encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
        encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create((BitmapSource)Firstimage.Source));
        using (var stream = File.Create(@"images//" + nametext.Text + ".png"))
            encoder.Save(stream);

        nametext.Text = "";
        text.Text = "";
        Firstimage.Source = null;

        cartinka.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        recept.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        tip.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        vnectiblock.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

        }


    }

    private void Openrecept_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        vivodcartinki.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        vivodtext.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;


        teb2.Items.Clear();

        teb2.SelectedIndex = -1;

        cartinka.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        recept.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        tip.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        vnectiblock.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;


        teb1.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        teb2.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        teb3.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        teb4.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        teb5.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        teb6.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        teb7.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        teb8.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        teb9.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        teb10.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;


    }

    private void Openspisok_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        teb1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        teb2.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        teb3.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        teb4.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        teb5.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        teb6.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        teb7.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        teb8.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        teb9.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        teb10.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

        cartinka.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        recept.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        tip.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        vnectiblock.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;



        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection conn = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=Database777.mdb;";

        conn.Open();

        String my_querry2 = "SELECT * FROM Десерт ";


        OleDbCommand cmd2 = new OleDbCommand(my_querry2, conn);
        OleDbDataReader reader = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            teb2.Items.Add(reader["Название рецепта"].ToString());
        }
        conn.Close();



        conn.Open();

        String my_querry4 = "SELECT * FROM Основное ";


        OleDbCommand cmd4 = new OleDbCommand(my_querry4, conn);
        OleDbDataReader reader3 = cmd4.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader3.Read())
        {
            teb4.Items.Add(reader3["Название рецепта"].ToString());
        }
        conn.Close();



        conn.Open();

        String my_querry5 = "SELECT * FROM Салат ";


        OleDbCommand cmd5 = new OleDbCommand(my_querry5, conn);
        OleDbDataReader reader4 = cmd5.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader4.Read())
        {
            teb6.Items.Add(reader4["Название рецепта"].ToString());
        }
        conn.Close();



        conn.Open();

        String my_querry6 = "SELECT * FROM Выпечка ";


        OleDbCommand cmd6 = new OleDbCommand(my_querry6, conn);
        OleDbDataReader reader5 = cmd6.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader5.Read())
        {
            teb8.Items.Add(reader5["Название рецепта"].ToString());
        }
        conn.Close();


        conn.Open();

        String my_querry7 = "SELECT * FROM Суп ";


        OleDbCommand cmd7 = new OleDbCommand(my_querry7, conn);
        OleDbDataReader reader6 = cmd7.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader6.Read())
        {
            teb10.Items.Add(reader6["Название рецепта"].ToString());
        }
        conn.Close();


    }



    private void Teb2_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        vivodtext.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        vivodcartinki.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;


        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection conn = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=Database777.mdb;";

        conn.Open();

        String my_querry2 = "SELECT * FROM Десерт ";


        OleDbCommand cmd2 = new OleDbCommand(my_querry2, conn);
        OleDbDataReader reader = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            vivodnamerecept.Text = reader["Название рецепта"].ToString();
            vivodtextrecept.Text = reader["Текст рецепта"].ToString();
        }
        conn.Close();
    }
```

Comment: А у вас реально в `my_querry` русские названия полей? и в базе соответственно..

Comment: @NewView Все названия полей русские

Comment: С кодировкой могут быть проблемы, попробуйте перевести на английский и без пробелов.

Comment: @NewView: это Access. Плохая СУБД, плохой стиль оформления таблиц ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ Дело вряд ли в кодировке

Comment: А как Вы делаете вывод, что информация пропала?

Comment: @Kir_Antipov Захожу в access и смотрю,потом плюсом мне данные из access мне понадобятся в этой же программе,а их нет

Comment: Так-с. А как Вы их выбираете из программы? И Вы уверены, что вставка вообще происходит?

Comment: @Kir_Antipov Захожу программу, выбираю внести рецепт ввожу название рецепта,текст рецепта ,нажимаю внести рецепт.В аксессе появляются данные.Потом из аксесса с помощью комбобоксов(каждый комбобокс отдельный вид блюда) выбираю внесенный рецепт,данные вносятся в текст блоки.НО ТЕПЕРЬ У МЕНЯ ПРИ КАЖДОМ ЗАПУСКЕ СТИРАЮТСЯ ДАННЫЕ.Такие дела..

Comment: Можете привести весь код, связанный с работой с базой?

Comment: @Kir_Antipov Обновил код выше.

Comment: В этом коде проблем с удалением данных попросту нет. Вы не удаляете папки Debug/Release перед запуском?) Или же не вызываете случаем пересоздание таблиц при старте программы?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91176/discussion-between-frallen-and-kir-antipov).

Comment: @Kir_Antipov Не не удаляю) Может быть и пересоздается бд,но где в этом коде идет пересоздание?Я просто добавил бд в проект и подключаюсь к ней

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Моя ошибка была в том что файл базы данных при каждой компиляции копируется в выходной каталог затирая старый файл и все изменения вместе с ним. 
Нужно в свойствах бд в vs установить свойство не копировать и поместить свою бд в папку с экзешником.
[image: не копировать]